# Invalid float error while integrating using integrate.quad

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, numerical-integration

I have a list:

```
q1 = [0,1.9488e-06,1.5473e-05,5.1829e-05,0.00012192,0.00023633,0.00040526,0.00063862,0.00094596,0.0013365,0.0018192,0.0024025,0.0030949,0.0039041,0.0048379,0.0059036]
```

which I am trying to integrate.
I have done the following:

```
def f(x):
    if (np.abs(x)<1e-10):
        res = x
    else:
        res = q2[:10]
    return res
x = np.arange(0,10,0.001)
def F(x):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate (x):
        y,err = integrate.quad(f,0,val)
        res[i] = y
    return res     
plt.plot(F(x))
```

when I try to run this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-88-ca3005760f4b>", line 19, in <module>
  plt.plot(F(x))

File "<ipython-input-88-ca3005760f4b>", line 14, in F
  y,err = integrate.quad(f,0,val)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 311, 
in quad points)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 376, 
in _quad
  return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this error?

Comment: Has your question been sufficiently addressed? If so, you can help everyone—you, me, and the community—by marking the correct answer with the checkbox to the left. Otherwise, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 0):

You're having this error because of these two lines in `f`:

```
    else:
        res = q2[:10]
```

Here, you're returning a slice of a list from the function. `quad` doesn't like that; according to [its documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html), it expects a function that returns a double (i.e. Python float), not a list.

While your intended output isn't given in your question, changing that line to

```
        res = q2[0]
```

or any other arbitrary index in `q2` corrects the error.